# How to use url_map.iter_rules with blueprint object instead of app

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a blueprint object "api" and a apis.py file where I have many APIs defined with api.route annotation. eg:

```
@api.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_info():
```

I want to iterate and get summary of all the APIs I have same as what we get when we use "url_map.iter_rules" on app object. How can we do this using api blueprint object? I have registered the blueprint in my init.py file using

```
from .api_1 import api as api_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you call `app.url_map.iter_rules()` after you've registered the blueprint you'll get all of the endpoints of the subdomains too, e.g.

api.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
api = Blueprint('api', __name__)
@api.route('/')
def call_api():
        return ""
```

init.py:

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from api import api

public = Blueprint('public', __name__)
@public.route('/')
def home():
        return render_template('public/home.html')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(public)
app.register_blueprint(api, subdomain='api')
print(list(app.url_map.iter_rules()))

[<Rule 'api|/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> api.call_api>,
 <Rule '/' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> public.home>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> static>]
```

Comment: I am initiating my app object in init.py as shown in my question and then  I have another file called apis.py where I have all my APIs defined. So I am not registering the blueprint in the apis.py file and I dont have app object there. I am simply importing the blueprint in apis.py using `from . import api`. Can you tell me what all I need to include in my apis.py or init.py? I need this to be sepearate API `api.route('/api/help', methods = ['GET'])` and I already have the code to use `app.url_map.iter_rules()` using app object in this

Comment: I want to use: whch reads the doc strings:                        `@api.route('/api/help', methods = ['GET'])
def help():
    func_list = {}
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        if rule.endpoint != 'static':
            docstring = app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__
            if docstring:
                func_list[docstring] = rule.rule
    return jsonify(func_list)`

Comment: ok so i've rearranged the modules in my answer, does this match your situation now? you don't need an app object in the modules.

Comment: What is `public.route('/')` for? Can't we skip this? Also I wanted this output in a json format with key:value = function_name:url is that possible?

Comment: you could skip it i guess, but you probably shouldn't, it's a good idea to expose this "default" route for health checks to see if your service is running. if you need json, you'll need to write some code to parse the output and put into a dict

Comment: ok I am very close on this. instead of `print(list(app.url_map.iter_rules()))` how can I store this in a variable which I can access in other .py files?

Comment: Can I not do something like `x = list(app.url_map.iter_rules())` and in other file I tried doing `from .. import x` which gave me `cannot import name 'x'`

Comment: yes this is right, have you got the file names right? also where in the code do you have the `x=...` line? it can't be inside a function, or inside `if __name__ = 'main'`

Comment: My project's init.py file has `x=list(app.url_map.iter_rules())` where I have registered my blueprint. Inside my project I have another package and inside init.py of the package I am trying to do an import. It's not in any function.

Comment: Ok I could fix the issue. Thanks a lot! There was some small spelling  mistake

Comment: In above example, is it possible to put url_map related code somewhere else apart from __init__.py. Like above, i have multiple blue prints registered in my application but for sitemap generation, i am looking for a better place instead of putting my code in __init__.py

Answer (score 1):

In case you find it useful, I made a function that shows me (only for testing) each of the url's according to the blueprints that are registered in the main application.
This is the only solution I have found to be able to print the endpoints separating them by the blueprint they belong to.
Of course you can create a function to be able to print the url_map of only one of the blueprints by passing the name in string format, or the blueprint itself.
Here are the examples:

```
from flask.logging import create_logger
def log_routes(app: Flask):

    log = create_logger(app)

    with app.app_context():
        """
        Maps every single endpoint for blueprint registered in the main application.
        Also shows methos available for each endpoint
        """

        log.info('MAP ROUTER')
        bps = app.blueprints
        for bp in bps:
            print('', end='\n')
            log.info(f'BLUEPRINT RULES: "{bp}"')
            for ep in app.url_map.iter_rules():
                bp_name = ep.endpoint.split('.')[0]
                if bp_name == bp:
                    log.debug(f'Endpoint: {ep} methods={ep.methods}')
```

Here is the example with a function that takes only the name of the blueprint from which you need to get its url_map:

```
def log_blueprint_urls(app: Flask, bp_name: str):

    log = create_logger(app)

    with app.app_context():
        """
        Maps every single endpoint for an specific blueprint in the main application.
        Also shows methos available for each endpoint
        """
        bps = app.blueprints
        if bp_name in bps:
            log.info(f'MAP ROUTER FOR BLUEPRINT "{bp_name}"')

            for ep in app.url_map.iter_rules():
                bp_name = ep.endpoint.split('.')[0]
                if bp_name == bp_name:
                    log.debug(f'Endpoint: {ep} methods={ep.methods}')
        else:
            log.critical(
                f'BLUEPRINT "{bp_name}" has not registered in main application')
```

Comment: In the second function you have name clash which results `bp_name == bp_name` which is always true.